# c# Index out of range exception (Image List)

Tags: c#, list

I have a little problem with a list of images. Can someone explain me what I does wrong?

```
    public static List<Image> Img  = new List<Image>();
    int i;

    public AlegereImagine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlegereImagine.Img [0] = Properties.Resources.image1;
        AlegereImagine.Img [1] = Properties.Resources.image22;
        AlegereImagine.Img [2] = Properties.Resources.image3;
        AlegereImagine.Img [3] = Properties.Resources.image4;
        AlegereImagine.Img [4] = Properties.Resources.image5;
        AlegereImagine.Img [5] = Properties.Resources.image6;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Imagine.Image = AlegereImagine.Img [1];
    }
```

Comment: AlegereImagine.Img [1] = Properties.Resources.image22;        is it right.

Comment: `.Add` to the list; it is not an array.  seems odd to load the list there because they could click the button before the picturebox clicks loads the list.

Comment: @Plutonix Are you sure is only this? http://snag.gy/lybBA.jpg

Comment: read the rest of the comment - if you click on the button BEFORE you click on the picture box there wont be anything in the list.  your app is very fragile